# ios Couldn't issue file extension for path

Tags: ios, file, path, appcelerator

I am facing a problem on iOS with physic files on my app.

So, in my app, i can download png, jpg and pdf files from a server. Then, i save those files in my app folder (**///var/mobile/Application//Documents/pic/xxxxxxxxx.pdf**).

It works fine....but...

When i make an update of my app (when simply generating new build and deploy it on a device), i can't open my files anymore and i have the error below :

```
Couldn't issue file extension for path /var/mobile/Applications/0A35985D-CB85-4BBD-B0DE-FB85E7DC89CA/Documents/pic/xxxxxxxxx.pdf
```

But before i try to open the file, i trace the path

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/0A35985D-CB85-4BBD-B0DE-FB85E7DC89CA/Documents/pic/xxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf
```

I have not the problem on Android...

I work with Appcelerator Titanium : some info about my environment

```
Operating System
Name                        = Mac OS X
Version                     = 10.11.6
Architecture                = 64bit
# CPUs                      = 4
Memory                      = 17179869184
Node.js
Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
npm Version                 = 2.11.3
Titanium CLI
CLI Version                 = 5.0.6
Titanium SDK
SDK Version                 = 5.2.0.GA
SDK Path                    = /Users/Epsilog/#/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.0.GA
Target Platform             = iphone
```

Thanks to all ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the the path ,you should look the path carefully,especially for the Case sensitive。Maybe running of Simulator is normally,it like to ignore the Case sensitive in my opinion.
good luck for you.